# What is the correct way to reference `AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup::LoadBalancerInfo?`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I am using CodeDeploy to deploy to an AutoScaling group behind a network load balancer, and I am running into the same issue as asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348919/codedeploy-the-specified-load-balancer-does-not-exist).

I have tried `Ref` and `GetAtt` for both types of names and neither works.

Is there an actual solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick and successful test with an existing Target Group (of ALB) and existing AutoScaling Group. I am sharing the template below in hope it may help you figure out issue with your template:

```
Parameters:
  DeploymentGroupName:
    Type: String
    Default: "MyDeploymentGroupName"
  VpcCidr:
    Type: String
    Default: "10.10.0.0/16"
  SubnetCidr:
    Type: String
    Default: "10.10.1.0/24"

Resources:
  myVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCidr

  mySubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVpc
      CidrBlock: !Ref SubnetCidr

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  mySNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: {}

  Application:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application

  DeploymentConfig:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig
    Properties:
      MinimumHealthyHosts:
        Type: FLEET_PERCENT
        Value: '25'

  DeploymentGroup:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref Application
      DeploymentConfigName: !Ref DeploymentConfig
      DeploymentGroupName: !Ref DeploymentGroupName
      AutoScalingGroups: 
        - "MyASGName"      
      LoadBalancerInfo:
       TargetGroupInfoList: 
          - Name: MYALBTargetGrpName
      DeploymentStyle:
        DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
      ServiceRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::<acc_number>:role/MyCodeDeployServiceRole
      TriggerConfigurations:
        - TriggerEvents:
            - DeploymentSuccess
            - DeploymentFailure
          TriggerName: MyTarget
          TriggerTargetArn: !Ref mySNSTopic
```

If you can share your complete template, I can try to reproduce and fix.

Comment: My complete template is over 500 lines long. I will take a look at this and try to figure out what is wrong first. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you never specify `ElbInfo` under `LoadBalancerInfo`; you only specify `TargetGroupInfoList`.

Comment: ElbInfoList -> ELBInfo is for Classic Load Balancer, 

TargetGroupInfoList -> TargetGroupInfo is for ALB...

I am not sure which one are you using.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codedeploy-deploymentgroup-loadbalancerinfo.html

Comment: I'm using a network load balancer; just updated the question to clarify.

Comment: It turns out that your comment was the correct answer. I had used ElbInfo instead of TargetGroupInfoList, so it was looking for a Classic Load Balancer and clearly failed to find one.